# JavaScript AddEventListener - Backspace

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

Hello I'm trying to get certain buttons to enable/disable based on what is inside a textbox. Be using the 'backspace' event I want to check the content of the textbox with each action so the buttons enabled/disabled states change accordingly. **'backspace' would be used for deleting content in the textbox, however 'backspace' isn't detected at all (using console.log to test).**

The following is the code (It works for 'c' but not for 'backspace'):

```js
document.addEventListener("keypress", function(event) 
{
  if (event.key == "c") 
  {
    console.log("C Pressed");
    document.getElementById("btnConvert").click();
  }

  var convertButton = document.getElementById("btnConvert");
  if (event.key == "Backspace") 
  {
    console.log("Backspace Pressed");
    var textboxContent = document.getElementById("txtFahrenheit").value;
    if (textboxContent.value == "" || textboxContent.value == "-")
    {
      convertButton.disabled = true;
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<button id="btnConvert" onclick="convertPressed()">Convert</button>
<input id="txtFahrenheit" type="text" onkeypress="return fNumOnly(event);" autofocus />
```

How can I get it to detect when 'backspace' is pressed? 
I tested with other letters and it worked fine, also tried doing 'event.keyCode == 8' but nothing detected.

Comment: var key = event.keyCode || event.charCode;

    if( key == 8 ) try this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `keydown` instead of `keypress` to detect Backspace properly:

```js
document.addEventListener("keydown", function(event) 
{
  if (event.key == "c") 
  {
    console.log("C Pressed");
    document.getElementById("btnConvert").click();
  }

  var convertButton = document.getElementById("btnConvert");
  if (event.key == "Backspace") 
  {
    console.log("Backspace Pressed");
    var textboxContent = document.getElementById("txtFahrenheit").value;
    if (textboxContent.value == "" || textboxContent.value == "-")
    {
      convertButton.disabled = true;
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<button id="btnConvert">Convert</button>
<input id="txtFahrenheit" type="text" autofocus />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).keyup(function(e)
{
    if(e.key == "c")
    {
        alert("C Pressed");
        document.getElementById("btnConvert").click();
    }
    var convertButton = document.getElementById("btnConvert");

    if(e.keyCode == 8)
    {
        alert('backspace trapped');
        var textboxContent = document.getElementById("txtFahrenheit").value;
        if (textboxContent.value == "" || textboxContent.value == "-")
        {
          convertButton.disabled = true;
        }
    }
});

<button id="btnConvert" onclick="convertPressed()">Convert</button>
<input id="txtFahrenheit" type="text" autofocus />
```